# Create Malformed Ether Frame?

Tags: python, scapy

I would expect this to be trivial but I can't get it to work.

I want to send a forged ARP using scapy in Python but I need to spoof the source MAC address as well in this scenario (vmac, vip, rip are all valid values)

```
op = 1
who_has_router = Ether(src=vmac)/ARP(op=op,psrc=vip,pdst=rip,hwsrc=vmac)
send(who_has_router)
```

The above appears as a malformed packet in Wireshark and is ignored by everyone on the network.

If I remove the `Ether()` layer it works fine (but then it doesn't spoof the source mac so isn't good enough in this case):

```
# This works exactly as expected
op = 1
who_has_router = ARP(op=op,psrc=vip,pdst=rip,hwsrc=vmac)
send(who_has_router)
```

How can I add the `Ether()` layer in Python/scapy without causing a malformed packet?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `send` function is used to send packets in layer 3, while your packet is a layer 2 one. You should use the `sendp` function.

See [`scapy`'s docs](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sending-packets) for further information:

> The `send()` function will send packets at layer 3. That is to say it will handle routing and layer 2 for you. The `sendp()` function will work at layer 2. It’s up to you to choose the right interface and the right link layer protocol.

The [official API documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf) states this as well:

> `send(pkts, inter=0, loop=0, verbose=None)`
>
> > Send packets at layer 3, using the `conf.L3socket` supersocket.
>
> `sendp(pkts, inter=0, loop=0, iface=None, iface hint=None, verbose=None)`
>
> > Send packets at layer 2 using the `conf.L2socket` supersocket.